# WPF and array of datagrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to develop something that - with WinForms - would be a proverbial "piece of cake". A dynamic set of data-bound datagrids. That initializes on application start. Sometimes there is a need for one, sometimes for five. At first it looked like too much for XAML. So I'm struggling with it with regular C#. which - with WPF - is insanely unfriendly and I'm hitting the wall again and again.

Or am I doing it all wrong? Is there any correct way to... "duplicate" / "clone" one datagrid designed and closed with XAML and reuse those clones as a dynamic array? Whenever I'm looking for a solution to more and more WPF obstacles (i.e. something as simple (with WinForms) as dynamic row coloring), I find sometimes XAML solutions. plain code solutions are extremely rare. even if try to "translate" XAML to regular code, I miss a lot of properties / methods (or maybe they are named differently). anyway - it's like people these days turn to XAML completely. are arrays of more complex controls that uncommon? I found some examples of button array bound to some table. and that's pretty much it. plus it never worked for an array of datagrids...

Comment: With XAML this task is not just a piece but an entire cake...As your question sounds like you just started out using WPF ('At first it looked like too much for XAML') take some time and read about ItemsControl, ItemTemplates and Binding mechanisms as shown in Robs answer

Answer (score 1):

This is just a prototype of how binding can yield fast results with minimal code written.

```
<Window x:Class="testtestz.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GridViews}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the code behind.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace testtestz
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<object> myData = new List<object>()
            {
                new { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
                new { Id = 2, Name = "Mary" },
                new { Id = 3, Name = "Anna" },
            };

            GridViews.Add(new MyGrid { Data = myData});
            GridViews.Add(new MyGrid { Data = myData });
            GridViews.Add(new MyGrid { Data = myData });

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public List<MyGrid> GridViews { get; } = new List<MyGrid>();
    }

    public class MyGrid
    {
        public IEnumerable<object> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you can bind almost anything you like so MyGrid class could very well have all the properties needed to create these grids. So for instance, you can have column definitions such as Header texts, column widths and such...